# Edit or delete all selection match highlightnings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I select a word, I get all matches highlit.

How do I edit or remove all occurrences all at the same time?

[image]

In this example, I woluld like to change all occurences to `param`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to make use of VS2022's Multiple Caret functionality.

Once you've made the initial selection you can use `Edit -> Multiple Carets -> Insert Carets At All Matching` functionality.

By default, this function is mapped to: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

This will add a new caret to each of the highlighted/matching sections allowing you to edit them simultaneously.

Multi-caret support in VS2022 is quite extensive. You can explore more options in [the official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2022#multi-caret-selection)